# How can I refresh Silverlight controls?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

How can I refresh a Silverlight listbox or datagrid? When I bind items the listbox or datagrid doesn't refresh until I click inside the control. This is annoying as I cannot see added items runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) and [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

By doing this the collection informs the view that it's changed so that the view can refresh itself.

From the `ObservableCollection` page:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

The area is a little large to go into in an answer on Stack Overflow, but there is plenty of information about these on the MSDN and other questions asked here. If, after reviewing the documentation, you have a specific question post that.

Comment: @D. Veloper - the second link should give you a good grounding in dependency properties. I don't know of any other sources you might find useful - there are plenty out there, but I usually find the MSDN or Stack Overflow have what I need.